# How to set-up local domain for DNS lookup?

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan

I have set my LAN local domain to be `local.example.com` on my router, an ordinary Verizon FiOS wireless broadband router with no special configuration.

All of the hosts are apparently being correctly assigned their host name, e.g.:

```
$ hostname
pc.local.example.com
```

Yet, a lookup for the host yields:

```
$ nslookup $(hostname)
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   pc.local.example.com
Address: 12.34.56.78
```

where `12.34.56.78` is the address provided by my external web hosting service, e.g. serving `www.example.com` on the Internet.

How can I configure DNS on my LAN's router to resolve the correct local addresses, e.g., `192.168.1.x`, as opposed to performing this lookup via the DNS server addresses it is configured to use?

Comment: You need a router that allows you to host your own local DNS.

Comment: Actually his router appears to be caching DNS, however my router does that too.. Just no method to add local DNS entries in many routers. @qasdfdsaq

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this - you'll see below that this was simply an error on my part when setting up the router configuration. All works as expected once corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved.

The local domain was incorrectly entered in the router's configuration as `local.exampl.com` (notice the missing `e`).

Upon correcting this, the local host names are, of course, resolving correctly:

```
$ nslookup $(hostname)
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Name:   pc.local.example.com
Address: 192.168.1.2
```

Human error at work once again!